# How to parse times that may or may not have decimal seconds in Python (2.7)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, strptime

How can I have strptime optionally use the decimal seconds when parsing? I'm looking for a concise way to parse both `%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S.%f` and `%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S`.

With the %f I recive error:

```
ValueError: time data '20130807-13:42:07' does not match format '%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S.%f'
```

Comment: try except around that line that raises the error? If one fails, try another format. Or, check if your string contains a dot and apply the good format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t = t.rsplit('.', 1)[0]
time.strptime('%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S.%f', t)
```

Or just make sure to add a decimal:

```
if not '.' in t:
    t += '.0'
time.strptime('%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S.%f', t)
```

This should do it.

Comment: Did you mean `.rsplit()` perhaps?

Comment: Yepp, you got me *bear* handed (clumsy paws) :)

Comment: @Adam Yes, it would. If you need it to be accurate you could do another option (i'll edit that in)

Comment: Interesting, I like how concise this option is with only adding two lines!

Comment: @Adam I'm a man of small words, as long as it's not in the comment section :)

Comment: Accepted for brevity and that a non-millisecond datetime isn't *exceptional* in my case. Thanks Torxed!

Comment: Also as a note, I changed the call to datetime since I want the whole date and all.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
import time

def timeFormatCheck(input):
    try:
        output = time.strptime(input, '%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S.%f') #or you could even return
    except ValueError:
        output = time.strptime(input,'%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S') #or you could even return
    return output
```

Or if you want a boolean value, try this:

```
import time

def isDecimal(input):
    try:
        time.strptime(input, '%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S.%f')
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Comment: isDecimal would suggest that the function returns True or False. I would call that function something like : `convert_to_datetime`